# Signalling Error when doing peer connection using WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have been trying to get my peer connection working for my application as seen in the picture below:

[image: console log]

As you can see, it shows that the peer connection has happened but there's been some incompatibility error which may be due to *adapter.js* shown in the next picture.

[image: error log]

Would be grateful if anyone knew how to fix this thanks!

I also added the code I'm using through pastebin for your viewing.
https://pastebin.com/WHCugjig

```
'use strict';

var localStream;
var remoteStream;
var pc;
var isInitiator;

var pcConfig = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }
  ]
};

// Define action buttons.
const callButton = document.getElementById('callButton');
const hangupButton = document.getElementById('hangupButton');

/////////////////////////////////////////////

var socket = io.connect();

var room = prompt('Enter room name:');

socket.emit('create or join', room);

socket.on('created', function(room) {
  console.log('Created room ' + room);
  isInitiator = true;
  startVideo();
});

socket.on('created', function(room) {
  isInitiator = false;
  startVideo();
  createPeerConnection(isInitiator);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendMessage(message) {
  socket.emit('message', message);
}

// This client receives a message
socket.on('message', function(message) {
  if (message.type === 'offer') {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(
      new RTCSessionDescription(message),
      function() {},
      onCreateSessionDescriptionError
    );
    pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onCreateSessionDescriptionError);
  } else if (message.type === 'answer') {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(
      new RTCSessionDescription(message),
      function() {},
      onCreateSessionDescriptionError
    );
  } else if (message.type === 'candidate') {
    pc.addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate({
        candidate: message.candidate
      })
    );
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

// Set up initial action buttons status: disable call and hangup.
callButton.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;

// Add click event handlers for buttons.
callButton.addEventListener('click', callStart);
hangupButton.addEventListener('click', hangupCall);

function startVideo() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true
    })
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(function(e) {
      alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });
}

function gotStream(stream) {
  try {
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
  } catch (error) {
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }
  localStream = stream;
  callButton.disabled = false;
}

function callStart() {
  createPeerConnection();
  pc.addStream(localStream);
  callButton.disabled = true;
  hangupButton.disabled = false;
  pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
      console.log('icecandidate event:', event);
      if (event.candidate) {
        sendMessage({
          type: 'candidate',
          label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
          id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
          candidate: event.candidate.candidate
        });
      } else {
        console.log('End of candidates.');
      }
    };
    pc.ontrack = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
    return;
  }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  try {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
  } catch (error) {
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  }
  remoteStream = event.stream;
}

function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
  console.log('setLocalAndSendMessage sending message', sessionDescription);
  sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}

function handleCreateOfferError(event) {
  console.log('createOffer() error: ', event);
}

function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
  console.log('Failed to create session description: ' + error.toString());
}

function hangupCall() {
  pc.close();
  pc = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a running version of the signaling server it is somewhat hard to debug this. Anyway...

You are calling setLocalAndSendMessage according to the debug log.
Then you get the "Failed to create session description" error twice which suggests that the code for receiving a message with type=offer is called.
Now why that happens depends on your signaling server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I unfortunately only started coding recently and I am not really certain what you mean by the signalling server as in the code itself, I have used socket.io which from what I understand is the signalling server.

Comment: did you implement that signaling server all by yourself? You might be better of trying to understand the code from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#7

Comment: Yes I have used that code labs code, I have an entire index.js file which is basically a duplicate of theirs but its still having errors with the adapter.js and also something to do with it being unable to set remote answer in stable state